# How to get Circle Bounds on Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, bounds

I am trying to find out if the current location of the user is inside a circle. I have this code right now.

```
  Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(14.635594, 121.032962))
     .radius(80)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     );
 map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
         Location.distanceBetween( 
                circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude,pLat,pLong, distance);

            if( distance[0] > circle.getRadius()  ){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Outside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }





 public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         pLat = location.getLatitude();

            // Getting longitude of the current location
          pLong = location.getLongitude();
```

The toast displays outside even though I am clearly inside the circle. I tried this code

```
LatLng latlng = new LatLng (pLat,pLong);
QC.contains(latlng);
```

where QC is a LatLngBounds variable. I wonder if `Circle` has also `contains` functionality to know if the user is inside the circle or is there a possible workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

multiply your latitude and longitude values by 1e6, bcoz those values are in microbytes.

[more info about microbyte conversion](http://www2.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=degrees%20vs%20microdegrees%20)

Comment: I did this . `to.setLatitude(pLat / 1E6);` and I was able to get the actual distance, in meters. why is that?

Comment: I think there is a problem. I tried changin the values of my lat and long, however the distance remains the same.

Comment: did you multiply getLatitude() from 1e6 or divide

Comment: I tried divide. However, as I said, I changed my coordinates and still the distance between them is still the same. However, I still can't find the correct algorithm that will compute between the center of the circle and the user location

Comment: have you tried the function of circle geomatry to identify the given node is inside the circle or not. I think it is better to use. bcoz may be the distanceBetween() method is return the road distance of given points not the actual distance

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Criteria Please try this

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        if (location != null)
        {
// this will animate you to the current location
             map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                     new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()), 13));
```

Comment: haha okay i didnt see it @MiguelRivera so u posted 2 question of same type ? so u got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected double latti;
    protected double longi;
    protected double radius;
   1/ MainActivity extends Activity implements  LocationListener
   2/locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,this);
   3///Add circle
     circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(47.974593,0.217905))
            .radius(80)
            .strokeColor(Color.CYAN));
}
    4/radius=circle.getRadius();
    5/onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       latti = location.getLatitude();
      longi = location.getLongitude();

      float[] distance = new float[1];
 Location.distanceBetween(latti,longi,circle.getCenter().latitude,circle.getCenter().longit ude, distance);

      showToast(distance[0]);   

}

private void showToast(float distance) {

if(distance>radius)
{
  remarque="Alarm Out Zone";
}
else{
remarque="Inside Zone";
 }
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitude:"+latti+"\nLongitude:"+longi+"\n"+remarque,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```